# Can $y'' = e^y$ be converted into a linear ODE through successive variable substitutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the following second-order nonlinear ODE:
$$y'' = e^y$$
The solution to this ODE is known precisely:
$$y = \ln\left(\frac{1}{2}c_{1}\left(\tanh^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c_1(c_2+x^2)}\right)-1\right)\right)$$
Given this knowledge about the solution, **is there any way to transform this ODE into a linear one using successive changes of variables**?

A motivating example; consider the first-order analogue $y' = e^y$, which has the solution:

$$y = \ln\left(\frac{1}{c - x}\right)$$

If I wanted to transform this nonlinear ODE into a linear one, I might consider the following coordinate transformation, $y = \ln(z)$; doing so generates the following nonlinear (but algebraic) ODE for $z$:

$$z' = z^2$$

Following up with another change of variables $z = w^{-1}$, we now find a linear ODE for $w$:

$$w' = -1, \quad w = c - x$$

and the solution for $y$ can be found trivially by applying all the coordinate changes to the solution of the linear ODE.

In short, by observing that the solution is a composition of operations on a relatively simple function ($c - x$), we could apply those operations consecutively on the ODE to eventually get a linear ODE. **Can we do that for $y'' = e^y$ too?**

Comment: Multiply by $y'$ to get $y'' y' = y' e^y$ which can be written $[y'^2/2]' = [e^y]'$ and you can integrate this and take it from there

Comment: @Winther  As much as I like that suggestion, the OP seems to be asking something else.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''=e^y$$
First substitution :  $\quad y'=u(y)$

$y''=u'(y)y'=u'(y)u(y)$
$$uu'=e^y$$
Second substitution :$\quad v(y)=u^2$

$v'=2uu'=2e^y$
$$v'(y)=2e^y\quad\text{is a linear ODE.}$$

To make it more obvious, let :

$X=y\quad$ and $\quad v(y)=Y(y)=Y(X)$.
$$Y'(X)=2e^X$$

Solving (outside the scope of the question) :

This is a linear first order separable ODE.

$v(y)=2\int e^y dy=2e^y+C_1$

$u=\pm\sqrt{2e^y+C_1}=\frac{dy}{dx}$

$x=\pm\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{2e^y+C_1}} = \pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{C_1}}\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{C_1}e^y}\right)+C_2$

$\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{C_1}e^y}=\tanh\left(\frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2}(x-C_2) \right)$

$e^y=\frac{C_1}{2}\left(\tanh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2}(x-C_2) \right)-1\right)$

$y=\ln\left(\frac{C_1}{2}\left(\tanh^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{C_1}}{2}(x-C_2) \right)-1\right)\right)$